# Python (tkinter) - Auto-left click when right clicking

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a GUI using python with the tkinter library. I've created a table that imports data without issue and I'm able to select (highlight) individual cells and right click on them to bring up a menu for that cell. The problem is I first have to left-click on the cell to highlight/select it before right-clicking on it to bring up it's menu. If I left-click one cell and then right click a different cell, it brings up a menu for that highlighted cell, not that one that I right-clicked on.

My code is a bit too large to post but I'm hoping I can get some general ideas or sample code on how when I right-click on a cell, it selects it as well.

Thank you

Comment: Your right-click code is probably checking which the currently highlighted entry is, and then displaying a context menu based off of that. You probably want to recalculate the currently highlighted entry (however your left-click does it, you probably want it in a function) and then query for the context menu.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We don’t need your whole program, just a new program with the same behavior.